# Has anyone faced the typeError : immutable in auth.js callback?

Tags: mongoose, next.js, next-auth

```
export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,    
  signIn,        
  signOut,
} = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GitHub({         
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,    
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
      await connectToDb;
      console.log(user.email);
      const dbUsers = await User.find();
      console.log(dbUsers);

      return true;
    },
  },
});
```

whenever i use

```
 console.log(user.email);
      const dbUsers = await User.find();
      console.log(dbUsers);
```

inside that callbacks i am facing TypeError: Immutable

how do i solve it. It stills works when connecting the database.But when it comes to the `const dbUsers = await User.find()` it shows me the above error. I don't know how to avoid I was watching a tutorial from youtube and I implemented typescript in my exercise.

Comment: `export const runtime = 'node'` can you add this to the top of nextAuth config file and then try

Comment: thanks bro i think i had something wrong during my project setup. when i created a new project it works

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because NextAuth is Edge compatible, but some of the database adapters, such as Prisma, are not. If any of your files are configured to have a runtime on Edge, you'll likely encounter this error.

The solution is to locate the route.ts file in your `app/api/[...nextauth]` folder and set the runtime to Node JS or completely remove the runtime variable from your route.ts file.

Your `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts` should resemble the following:

```
export { GET, POST } from "@/auth";
export const runtime = "nodejs"; // You can optionally remove this, but if it's set to 'edge', there will be an error when using edge incompatible adapters.
```